# Cannot use Random method in Console Application in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, random

Is it not possible to use Random method in Console Application in Delphi? It won't compile and shows the error:

> '.' expected but '(' found

When I try to do the same thing in normal application (with windows), it works.

The whole code I'm trying to compile is here:

```
program random;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses SysUtils;

var iRan:integer;

begin
  Randomize;
  iRan:=Random(10);
  writeln(iRan);
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: It's a shame that a question providing everything we ask for that's usually missing from so many other questions on this site (MCVE, clear error message, clear problem statement) is attracting so many down-votes. This really does nothing to help new users to understand 'what makes a good question' on this site. :(

Comment: I see zero reason why this question deserves a downvote. Just because it's trivial for most of us, doesn't mean it will be such an obvious mistake to a beginner. It really is a good question, as Craig says, follows all the rules, and is also helpful for future readers. I've seen the domino effect many times - one person down-votes, and everyone follows with the trend.

Comment: @JerryDodge Agreed with you

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the fact that this question could be caused by any procedure matching program name makes it not very search-friendly nor useful to others. Perhaps that was the reasoning for downvoters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your program is named `random`.  That name hides that name in `System`.

Either use a different program name or fully qualify the function, `System.Random`.